# Automatically "Resolve as Won't Fix" issues that are suppressed inline

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop

I have the convention for FxCop / Code Analysis errors:

- **Suppressed Inline** Won't Fix
- **Global Suppressed** Genuine Technical Debt, should fix

When generating reports with SonarQube, the supressed inline ones are being flagged as Technical Debt:

[image: SonarQube]

I can go through these and select "Resolve as Won't Fix". Is there a way to do this automatically for a project?

**Update 20/06**:
I have updated the plugin to C# 5.3, which is now ignoring any supressed files, but *including* the ones in global suppressions. [I've tried to stop SonarQube from processing the global suppression file, but with no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841029/how-do-i-get-sonarqube-to-ignore-the-globalsuppressions-cs-file).

**Current Versions**:

- **SonarQube**: Version 5.2
- **C# Pugin**: 5.3

Comment: Is 5.2 the version of SonarQube or of the C# Plugin ? Please specify version for each of those.

Comment: @Nicolas updated to the current state of my problem.