# How do I get SonarQube to ignore the GlobalSuppressions.cs file?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I want to exclude the `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file from SonarQube analysis so that it doesn't look at the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage` directives in there.

These are in the root of each project, but not in the root where the solution is: E.g.
[image]

I set this in the admin:

[image]

Namely, `**/GlobalSuppressions.cs`.

There are many projects in each solution, so I would like to avoid referencing each individually if possible.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to use a Powershell script to clear the `globalsupressions.cs` file and alter the ruleset from one that errored (`CodeAnalysisRulesErrors.ruleset` or `CodeAnalysisRulesUnitTestsErrors.ruleset`) to one that threw warnings (`CodeAnalysisRules.ruleset` or `CodeAnalysisRulesUnitTests.ruleset`), that way SonarQube correctly reported on the technical debt.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string]$localWorkspace
)
begin{}
process
{
  try
  {
    $localWorkspace =  "$($env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)\$($localWorkspace)"
    $localWorkspace = $localWorkspace -replace "/" , "\"
    $localWorkspace = $localWorkspace -replace "\\" , "\"

    Write-Verbose $localWorkspace

    #Work out top level directories, excluding system dirs
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$topLevelDirs = @()
    $topLevelItem = Get-ChildItem $localWorkspace -Exclude @("node_modules", "packages", "Common", ".nuget", ".vs", "_Resharper.Caches", "Javascript")
    foreach ($item in $topLevelItem)
    {
        if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) {
            Write-Verbose $item
            $topLevelDirs.Add($item)
        }
    }

    foreach ($topLevelFolder in $topLevelDirs)
    {
        Write-Verbose $topLevelFolder
        $ServiceDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $topLevelFolder -Filter GlobalSuppressions.cs -Recurse
        foreach ($sd in $ServiceDirs)
        {
            Write-Verbose $sd
            Clear-Content $sd.FullName
        }

        Get-ChildItem -Path $topLevelFolder -Filter *.csproj -Recurse | ForEach {
             Write-Verbose $_.FullName
             (Get-Content $_.FullName | ForEach  { $_ -replace 'CodeAnalysisRulesErrors.ruleset', 'CodeAnalysisRules.ruleset' }) | Set-Content $_.FullName
             (Get-Content $_.FullName | ForEach  { $_ -replace 'CodeAnalysisRulesUnitTestsErrors.ruleset', 'CodeAnalysisRulesUnitTests.ruleset' }) | Set-Content $_.FullName
        }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    write-host "Caught an exception:" 
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" 
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
  }
}
end{}
```